# Compact operators on $L^2([a,b])$: Are the dimensions of eigenspaces the same on dense subspaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I am looking for either an obvious answer or some assessment of how difficult this is.

Consider a compact operator $K$ from $L^2([a,b])\to L^2([a,b])$ with an eigenvalue at $\lambda_0\neq 0.$ Consider the (not closed) subspace $A=C([a,b])$ with the $L^2$ inner product. Suppose we know that in $A,$ the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_0$ is $n$. Given that $A$ is dense, due to Lusins Theorem, it's hard to picture there being additional eigenfunctions in $L^2$ that are not in $A.$ Is my intuition correct or does it depend on $K$? I guess I'm looking for a version of the Fredholm alternative on dense subspaces. In general, it seems harder to calculate the dimension of the eigenspace in $L^2$ than $C$ since pointwise arguments can be made on $C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors $v \in L^2$ such that $Kv = \lambda_0 v$ form a finite-dimensional subspace $W$  of $L^2$.  The intersection of that with $C([a,b])$ is a subspace
of dimension $n$.
But the dimension of $W$ could be any integer $\ge n$.

The fact that continuous functions are dense is irrelevant: the continuous approximations of a discontinuous function in $W$ won't be eigenfunctions for eigenvalue $\lambda_0$.

It's easy to cook up examples
of this: just take $n$ linearly independent continuous functions and $m$ functions
which each have a single discontinuity at one point (different for each function),
and let $K$ be a projection on the linear span of these $m+n$ functions.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You have clearly laid out that I can't establish this fact rigorously. It does seem to me like it probably (by chance) holds in a lot of modeling settings.